# Modify DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I create an object

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

It is set to current date **2011-04-01 21:43:40**. I try the following

```
$date->modify('midnight');
```

I expect the object to set to **2011-04-01 00:00:00**. But nothing happened. Object hadn't beed modified, and continue to have a **2011-04-01 21:43:40** date. I just want to reset the time to midnight (00:00:oo).

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/w5RAF0Lh

This piece of code (with midnight) will not work without date.timezone setting

UPDATE: this piece of code requires PHP 5.3.6 to work correctly. In previous versions `DateTime::modify('midnight')` didn't work

Comment: It doesnt help. I set up default timezone in php.ini - and nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you restarted apache or php? Have you turned all error reporting on?

Comment: yes. of course. PHPinfo() shows the current timezone set. DateTime::getTimezone also show the correct timezone. But DateTime::modify still doest work with time (today, midnight), only with date. But it works with $date->modify('+12 hours'); ok. It is very strange.

Comment: Well, I tested on latest 5.3.3 and it doesn't work either. But I installed 5.3.6 and it works. Please update your PHP.

Comment: I just gett off these OOP classes and use so native strtotime, date etc. DateTime, DatePeriod, DateInterval are very and very buggy in php 5.2 as min.

Comment: @Molfar 5.2 is EOL already. Consider upgrading to 5.3 branch because no even security updates will be released for 5.2 from now on.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into trouble with this not working prior to PHP 5.3.6. One workaround is to do this: `$date = date_create()->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');` because `$date->modify('midnight');` wasn't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Got a few questions, perhaps the will help illuminate the problem...

Is a timezone set in your php.ini file?

After you create the new DateTime() object are you using var_dump() or some other function to view its parameters and get the set date?

Have you tried and been successful passing other date and time formats into the modify method?

Comment: timezone is not set in php.ini. I create DateTime() object like $date = new DateTime(); I user Crumo to view $date object (Drupal, Devel module). The following $date->modify('+5 days'); works fine. The problem is when trying to modify time, nod date. Even $date->modify('11:00'); doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I did a fast check on codepad.org and it seems to me too that time won't modify whatever I try. Strange.

Comment: I would try setting a default timezone in the php.ini, especially if time modifications aren't working but day mods are.

Comment: If you don't have a timezone set in php.ini, you should be getting a big fat warning in your code.  Please ensure you're developing with error reporting and display errors enabled: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine checks if the `DateTime` object has changed its reference.
Modifying an object doesn’t change the reference, so for doctrine, this is not a change.
Use `new \DateTime('midnight')` instead.

Comment: Please explain more. Your answer likes comment, not answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
However the returned date was correct, so what I did is:

```
@$date->modify('midnight');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today midnight')));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```